# Is it possible to use NancyFx modules and a WebAPI controller together in the same application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nancy, httplistener, owin

I have a self-hosting Owin HttpListener application using NancyFx.

I am wondering if it is possible to add to this project a WebApi Controller and make sure that a certain route is served only by this WebApi Controller.

It would be really nice to see an example of this working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is only possible if you if you use OWIN and HttpListener from the Katana Project. You can either host Nancy and WebApi on separate paths using the [map middleware](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/Mapping/MapExtensions.cs):

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/nancy", branch => branch.UseNancy())
           .Map("/webapi", branch => branch.UseWebApi());
    }
}
```

Or you can configure Nancy to pass-through to subsequent middleware if, for example, Nancy is responding with a 404:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseNancy(opt => 
                     opt.PassThroughWhenStatusCodesAre(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
           .UseWebApi();
    }
}
```

Comment: this was very helpful to me